# After uploading to s3 with ng-file-upload, why can't I open the downloaded file?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, amazon-s3, ng-file-upload

I am using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to upload directly to Amazon S3.  I am able to get an mp4 file uploaded and I can download it.  The main issue is when I download the file and I try to open it in my mp4 player, I get this error

***An error occurred: could not determine type of stream.***

Also, I notice that the original file is 570.1 kb but when I re-download it after uploading to s3, it is 571.4 kb.

Below is the ng-file-upload coad, where result.fields is using the signed credentials similar to that generated in the wiki example [here](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/wiki/Direct-S3-upload-and-Node-signing-example).

```
        var myUrl = 'https://' + nameOfBucket + '.s3.amazonaws.com/' + result.fields.key;
        Upload.upload({
            url: myUrl, //s3Url
            fields: result.fields, //credentials
            headers: { "Content-Type": file.type, "x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"},
            method: 'PUT',
            file: file
         });
```

Comment: You should NOT set the `content-type` header. read the docs for S3 upload.